# MySql Workbench 8.0 cant connect remotly

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to set up a database for a class project and we are using MySqlWorkbench 8.0. I am able to set up a database and connect to it locally but I cant seem to get remote connections to work. I have already researched the problem and here are a list of things I've already tried. (I am using windows 10)

1. I have looked at the my.ini file for the bind-adress property as this seemed to be the most common problem but it isn't even in the my.ini file.
2. I have added a user using this query to grant permission for others to connect using other ips

`CREATE USER 'USER'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';`
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USER'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`
`FLUSH privileges;`

3. I have tried disabling my firewalls as well as just allowing connections to port 3306 to no avail

Anything would help. All of the answers i found online were outdated or pertained to the bind-adress which i cannot find in the my.ini file

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, Let double-check these points: but this's NOT a problem of `MySqlWorkbench`

1. Same as you did so far. Update bind-address to 0.0.0.0 which accept all
2. Yes, It's same but double check by `select user, host from mysql.user;`
3. NO disable the firewall, add TCP port of mysql
4. If you're using a cloud server you have to add MySQL port in network policy setting, if you're using LAN you may need to open port in the gateway

When you make sure all work then I belive that you can connect via command line or `MySqlWorkbench` or any SQL Tools which support MySQL.

Comment: I have done all of these things and I still can't connect remotely.

Comment: Hmm, that weird, are you connect using TLS/SSL?. I can help via TeamViewer if you need